# menu na vertical com select

Tags: javascript, html, css, front-end

Alguém poderia me dar um norte sobre como exibir um menu na vertical quando os itens do primeiro `select` for selecionado, eu estou fazendo isso de uma maneira bem tosca, pois se verificar notarão que eu coloquei `margin-top` para subir o elemento para cima do primeiro elemento, visto que, são em pilha.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
      function optionCheck(){
        var opcaoModSelecionada = document.getElementById("tipoModalidadeEnsino").value;
        if(opcaoModSelecionada == "gra"){
          document.getElementById("primary-list-course").style.visibility = "visible";
          document.getElementById("secundary-list-course").style.visibility = "hidden";
          document.getElementById("third-list-course").style.visibility = "hidden";

        } else if (opcaoModSelecionada == "pgr"){
          document.getElementById("secundary-list-course").style.visibility = "visible";
          document.getElementById("primary-list-course").style.visibility = "hidden";
          document.getElementById("third-list-course").style.visibility = "hidden";

        } else if (opcaoModSelecionada == "ext"){
          document.getElementById("third-list-course").style.visibility = "visible";
          document.getElementById("primary-list-course").style.visibility = "hidden";
          document.getElementById("secundary-list-course").style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
      }
    </script>
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins&display=swap');

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 40%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.course {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 40%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: bisque;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.secundary-list-course {
  margin-top: -25px;
}

.third-list-course {
  margin-top: -25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
    <title>EXIBIÇÃO POR CAMPO SELECIONADO</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container">
      <label for="tipModalidadeEnsino">Selecione a Modalidade</label>
      <select id="tipoModalidadeEnsino" name="tipoModalidadeEnsino" onchange="optionCheck()">
        <option value="0" selected>-- Selecione uma das opções --</option>
        <option value="gra">Graduação</option>
        <option value="pgr">Pós-graduação</option>
        <option value="ext">Extensão</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="primary-list-course course" id="primary-list-course">
      <label for="tipoCurso1"><span style="color:blueviolet">Cursos de Graduação</span></label>
      <select id="tipoCurso1" name="tipoCurso1">
        <option selected>-- Escolha o curso --</option>
        <option>Administração</option>
        <option>Direito</option>
        <option>Ciencias Biológica</option>
        <option>Sistemas de Informação</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="secundary-list-course course" id="secundary-list-course">
      <label for="tipoCurso2"><span style="color: blueviolet">Cursos de Pós-graduação</span></label>
      <select id="tipoCurso2" name="tipoCurso2">
        <option selected>-- Escolha o curso --</option>
        <option>Engenharia de Software</option>
        <option>Cyber  Security</option>
        <option>Física</option>
        <option>Psicologia</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="third-list-course course" id="third-list-course">
      <label for="tipoCurso3"><span style="color: blueviolet">Cursos de Extensão</</label>
      <select id="tipoCurso3" name="tipoCurso3">
        <option selected>-- Escolha o curso --</option>
        <option>Inglês</option>
        <option>Mecatrônica</option>
        <option>SegInfo</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `display: none` em vez de `visibility: hidden`. Assim os selects adicionais ficarão sempre abaixo do select principal, e não vai precisar usar `margin-top` para posicioná-los. Um elemento com `display: none` não ocupa espaço no layout, ao contrário do `visibility: hidden`:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins&display=swap');

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 40%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.course {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 40%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: bisque;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
    <title>EXIBIÇÃO POR CAMPO SELECIONADO</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container">
      <label for="tipModalidadeEnsino">Selecione a Modalidade</label>
      <select id="tipoModalidadeEnsino" name="tipoModalidadeEnsino" onchange="optionCheck()">
        <option value="0" selected>-- Selecione uma das opções --</option>
        <option value="gra">Graduação</option>
        <option value="pgr">Pós-graduação</option>
        <option value="ext">Extensão</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="primary-list-course course" id="primary-list-course">
      <label for="tipoCurso1"><span style="color:blueviolet">Cursos de Graduação</span></label>
      <select id="tipoCurso1" name="tipoCurso1">
        <option selected>-- Escolha o curso --</option>
        <option>Administração</option>
        <option>Direito</option>
        <option>Ciencias Biológica</option>
        <option>Sistemas de Informação</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="secundary-list-course course" id="secundary-list-course">
      <label for="tipoCurso2"><span style="color: blueviolet">Cursos de Pós-graduação</span></label>
      <select id="tipoCurso2" name="tipoCurso2">
        <option selected>-- Escolha o curso --</option>
        <option>Engenharia de Software</option>
        <option>Cyber  Security</option>
        <option>Física</option>
        <option>Psicologia</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="third-list-course course" id="third-list-course">
      <label for="tipoCurso3"><span style="color: blueviolet">Cursos de Extensão</label>
      <select id="tipoCurso3" name="tipoCurso3">
        <option selected>-- Escolha o curso --</option>
        <option>Inglês</option>
        <option>Mecatrônica</option>
        <option>SegInfo</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <script>
function optionCheck(){
        var opcaoModSelecionada = document.getElementById("tipoModalidadeEnsino").value;
        if(opcaoModSelecionada == "gra"){
          document.getElementById("primary-list-course").style.display = "block";
          document.getElementById("secundary-list-course").style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById("third-list-course").style.display = "none";

        } else if (opcaoModSelecionada == "pgr"){
          document.getElementById("secundary-list-course").style.display = "block";
          document.getElementById("primary-list-course").style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById("third-list-course").style.display = "none";

        } else if (opcaoModSelecionada == "ext"){
          document.getElementById("third-list-course").style.display = "block";
          document.getElementById("primary-list-course").style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById("secundary-list-course").style.display = "none";
        }
      }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Exatamente o que precisava, porém o que seria esse xmargin-top? Iria editar a minha resposta porque estava dando Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined, vejo que você solucionou isso também na sua resposta. O que você fez?

Comment: `xmargin-top` é erro de digitação, é só `margin-top`.

Comment: @LucasInácio É porque esqueci de apagar onde tem xmargin-top... O erro no snippet era porque vc colocou as tags `<script type="text/javascript">` dentro co código JavaScript.

Comment: Certo, porém estou tentando carregar esse script e não está indo (estou carregando acima do fechamento da tag body), porém dispara o mesmo erro..

Comment: @LucasInácio  Alterei a resposta. Dá uma olhada.

Comment: Vi aqui, só mais uma dúvida, notei que seu select ficou abaixo da label, porém você não utilizou hr e nem nada, então o que fez?

Comment: @LucasInácio Não fiz nada. O select vai pra baixo da label quando a tela for mt pequena. Execute o snippet acima em tela cheia que o select ficará ao lado da label.

Answer (score 3):

Uma opção é colocar `position:absolute` nos cursos, e clocar `left` e `right` com `0`. Ai vc não precisa usar o `margin-top`, pois eles já vai ficar sobrepostos.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins&display=swap');

body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.container {
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
width: 40%;
height: auto;
background-color: #ddd;
}

.course {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
width: 40%;
height: auto;
background-color: bisque;
visibility: hidden;
}

.secundary-list-course {
/* margin-top: -25px; */
}

.third-list-course {
/* margin-top: -25px; */
}
    </style>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
  <title>EXIBIÇÃO POR CAMPO SELECIONADO</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <label for="tipModalidadeEnsino">Selecione a Modalidade</label>
    <select id="tipoModalidadeEnsino" name="tipoModalidadeEnsino" onchange="optionCheck()">
      <option value="0" selected>-- Selecione uma das opções --</option>
      <option value="gra">Graduação</option>
      <option value="pgr">Pós-graduação</option>
      <option value="ext">Extensão</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="primary-list-course course" id="primary-list-course">
    <label for="tipoCurso1"><span style="color:blueviolet">Cursos de Graduação</span></label>
    <select id="tipoCurso1" name="tipoCurso1">
      <option selected>-- Escolha o curso --</option>
      <option>Administração</option>
      <option>Direito</option>
      <option>Ciencias Biológica</option>
      <option>Sistemas de Informação</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="secundary-list-course course" id="secundary-list-course">
    <label for="tipoCurso2"><span style="color: blueviolet">Cursos de Pós-graduação</span></label>
    <select id="tipoCurso2" name="tipoCurso2">
      <option selected>-- Escolha o curso --</option>
      <option>Engenharia de Software</option>
      <option>Cyber  Security</option>
      <option>Física</option>
      <option>Psicologia</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="third-list-course course" id="third-list-course">
    <label for="tipoCurso3"><span style="color: blueviolet">Cursos de Extensão</span></label>
    <select id="tipoCurso3" name="tipoCurso3">
      <option selected>-- Escolha o curso --</option>
      <option>Inglês</option>
      <option>Mecatrônica</option>
      <option>SegInfo</option>
    </select>
  </div>


  <script type="text/javascript">
    function optionCheck(){
      var opcaoModSelecionada = document.getElementById("tipoModalidadeEnsino").value;
      if(opcaoModSelecionada == "gra"){
        document.getElementById("primary-list-course").style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("secundary-list-course").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("third-list-course").style.visibility = "hidden";

      } else if (opcaoModSelecionada == "pgr"){
        document.getElementById("secundary-list-course").style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("primary-list-course").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("third-list-course").style.visibility = "hidden";

      } else if (opcaoModSelecionada == "ext"){
        document.getElementById("third-list-course").style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("primary-list-course").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("secundary-list-course").style.visibility = "hidden";
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: estou fazendo como o @sam sugeriu, mas aprendi essa nova maneira que você passou que eu ainda não sabia, embora saiba bem pouco de css, valeu hugo!

Comment: @LucasInácio sem problemas meu caro. Essa é só uma alternativa, mas o position:absolute tem umas implicações meio chatas de tratar... para esse modelinho ai em particular poderia ser uma opção. E estude sim CSS, ele é fundamental. Valeu a força.

Comment: Estou caindo de cabeça, realmente indo a fundo, é que eu sou bem prematuro nisso ainda, valeu ai!

Answer (score 0):

**Questão**: Manter os sub items(sub categoria) sempre no topo após a escolha da categoria.

**Solução**: CSS Grid Layout

**CodePen**: [visualize o código/exemplo aqui](https://codepen.io/cheenZhen/pen/WNedGMV)

> **Obs**: Evite usar `display:none` quando um handler(manipulador de eventos) possa ocorrer muitas vezes em sua pagina. Isso gera **reflows** na **render tree** desnecessários, prejudicando a performance de sua aplicação web.
>   
> Caso queira saber mais sobre reflows e performance JavaScript: [leia este artigo](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2009/03/27/reflows-repaints-css-performance-making-your-javascript-slow/)

**Code snippets**:

- Markup(Pug)

```
- const diet = { lifeStyle:['vegetarian','vegan','common'], vegetables:['tomato','onion','broccoli',], proteins:['egg','cheese','tofu'], meat:['bovine','fish','sea'] }
section.bc-form
  form.bc-form__container
    div(class=`bc-form__field  life-style`)
      select(class=`bc-form__controller_select`)
        each type,ind in diet.lifeStyle
          option(class=`bc-form__controller` label=`${type}`)= type
    div(class=`bc-form__field  vegetables  has-selected`)
      select(class=`bc-form__controller_select`)
        each type,ind in diet.vegetables
         option(class=`bc-form__controller` label=`${type}`)= type
    div(class=`bc-form__field  proteins`)
      select(class=`bc-form__controller_select`)
        each type,ind in diet.proteins
         option(class=`bc-form__controller` label=`${type}`)= type
    div(class=`bc-form__field  meats`)
      select(class=`bc-form__controller_select`)
        each type,ind in diet.meat
         option(class=`bc-form__controller` label=`${type}`)= type
```

- Style(Sass)

```
.bc
  &-form
    &__container
      display: grid
    &__field
      padding: .3125rem
.vegetables,
.proteins,
.meats
  visibility: hidden
.has-selected
  grid-row: 2
  visibility: visible
```

- JS(Vanilla)

```
const all_fields = document.querySelectorAll(`.bc-form__field`)
const selection_field_vegetables = document.querySelector(`.vegetables`)
const selection_field_proteins = document.querySelector(`.proteins`)
const selection_field_meats = document.querySelector(`.meats`)
const controller_select_lifeStyle = document.querySelector(`.life-style`).children[0]

const setClass = (elem)=>elem.classList.add(`has-selected`)

const resetDefaultClassToAllFields = (event) =>{
  const targert = event.currentTarget
  all_fields.forEach((elem,ind)=>elem.classList.remove(`has-selected`))
  manageToFieldsSelected(targert)
}

const manageToFieldsSelected = (target)=>{
  switch(target.value){
    case `vegetarian`:
      setClass(selection_field_vegetables)
      break
    case `vegan`:
      setClass(selection_field_proteins)
      break
    case `common`:
      setClass(selection_field_meats)
      break
    default:
      setClass(selection_field_vegetables)
  }
}
controller_select_lifeStyle.addEventListener('change',resetDefaultClassToAllFields,false)
```

Comment: Cara copiar código do Codepen e colar aqui não é responder a pergunta

Comment: Make sense?! rs